# Placing generated list into drop-down on custom menu

Tags: menus, categories, list-authors

I'm trying to add categories and authors automatically into the custom menu as they are created (avoiding having to do it manually for each one).

I've modified [Alex Mill's code](http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/09/20/code-snippet-add-a-link-to-latest-post-to-wordpress-nav-menu/) and got to display a list of elements with the categories on the menu, buuut the problem is that the list of elements is ***outside* the ul of the menu** in itself. You can see what I mean [here](http://pazuzu.inwx.net/).

And here's my version of the code:

```
// Front end only, don't hack on the settings page
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
// Hook in early to modify the menu
// This is before the CSS "selected" classes are calculated
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'replace_placeholder_nav_menu_item_with_latest_post', 10, 3 );
}

// Replaces a custom URL placeholder with the URL to the latest post
function replace_placeholder_nav_menu_item_with_latest_post( $items, $menu, $args ) {

// Loop through the menu items looking for placeholder(s)
foreach ( $items as $item ) {

// Is this the placeholder we're looking for?
if ( '#latestpost' != $item->url )
continue;

// Get the categories
$latestpost = wp_list_categories( array(
'orderby' => name,
'show_count' => 0,
'exclude' => 3,
'title_li' => "",
) );

if ( empty( $latestpost ) )
continue;

// Replace the placeholder with the real URL
$item->url = get_permalink( $latestpost[0]->ID );
}

// Return the modified (or maybe unmodified) menu items array
return $items;
}
```

Any idea on how to place this generated list of elements inside the proper dropdown (in this case, TEST)?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 0):

> buuut the problem is that the list of elements is outside the ul of
>   the menu in itself.

I think part of the problem might be that `wp_list_categories()` is in *echo*-mode by default so `$latestpost` is always empty.

Please try it with these parameters instead:

```
// Get the categories
$latestpost = wp_list_categories( array(
  'orderby'    => name,
  'show_count' => 0,
  'exclude'    => 3,
  'title_li'   => "",
  'echo'       => 0,
) );
```

You can see the default arguments of `wp_list_categories()` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) in the Codex.

The problem with your code example is also that the output of `wp_list_categories()` is an HTML string, not an array. So this part: `$latestpost[0]->ID` has no meaning when `$latestpost` is an (empty) string.

Comment: Hi Birgire, the problem is not that they echo, is that they echo outside the main menu ul. I mean, they should appear, but just under ul li<-(this one being categories) ul li

Comment: On the case of the Categories, I fixed the issue installing [this plugin](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/add-descendants-as-submenu-items/), then creating a parent category called "Categories", that contains all categories. 

On the custom menu, I just add the "Categories" button to the menu and click on the checkbox that makes all descendants from this element (which are all other categories) appear automatically.

A rather tricky solution for what it should be a simple problem, but it works. 

Thanks Birgire also!

Comment: good you found a solution, maybe you should add it as an answer and accept it. ps: when you have an echo inside a function with a return it usually gives you a similar problem as you described.

Comment: I wanted to add is a solution but I don't have enough reputation! : )

Comment: ok - I added more explanations to my answer to hopefully show better where the problem is with the code example.